# Why does this bit of C# code with array initializer not refactor how I expect

Tags: c#, refactoring, array-initialization

I have the following code;

```
char[] leadingDot = { '.' };
string trimStart = fileName.TrimStart(leadingDot);
```

I cannot seem to figure out the syntax to combine it into a single line.  ReSharper has no suggestions either.

I completely understand why the following code doesn't work, let alone look right, but I would expect something like:

```
string trimStart = fileName.TrimStart( { '.' } );
```

It gives me the same vibe you get when you type `var x = null;` Ideas?

Comment: Use `new char[] { '.' }`

Comment: facepalm.  Didn't know char could be 'newed'.

Comment: @CarComp You're not making a new `char`, you're making a new `char[]`.

Comment: `fileName.TrimStart('.')`, `filename.TrimStart('.', ':')`, etc. There's an overload for one character, and an overload `TrimStart(params char[] trimChars)` that takes either an array of char, or any number of single char arguments which will be treated as an array internally.

Comment: To specifically address the question as it's stated in the title, you have to understand what is implied in the original context so that you can be explicit about it when the new context where that implication isn't possible. In this case, the implied part was `new char[]`. And then, in the new context, the syntax allows a *different* implication via the `params` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
string trimStart = fileName.TrimStart(new char[] { '.'});
```

Comment: I took it down to `string trimStart = fileName.TrimStart('.')`